# Using Street View VR in my app

Tags: java, android, virtual-reality, google-street-view

I'm using Android Studio and trying to show some chosen Street View paths in VR. I already have Street View running well and now I'm trying to show it in VR.

I have put the `com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView` in the layout and, inside onCreate in my class, referenced it to a `VrPanoramaView` variable through `findViewById`. Now I'm trying to show an image calling a method which I've defined in this class, loadPanoImage. This method loads an image from the storage and shows it through `loadImageFromBitmap`.

The problem is that it isn't able to show anything, even though I've followed a guide and I've done everything as showed. I've even tryed calling it in different parts of the code (before doing any other action, on clicking a button, before and after showing streetview) but I can't understand why it isn't working and how will I be able to use it to show images taken from StreetView (I don't know if I will be able to do it dinamically or I should download them and put them in the storage).

I'm putting part of the code for reference:

```
public class VrExperience extends FragmentActivity {

    Button buttonCitta;
    Button buttonMare;
    Button buttonMontagna;
    TextView titleTextView;

    // George St, Sydney
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
    // LatLng with no panorama
    private static final LatLng INVALID = new LatLng(-45.125783, 151.276417);

    //VrPanoramaView is inserted in the layout
    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
    //StreetViewPanorama is another class in my project which shows Street View
    private StreetViewPanorama mStreetViewPanorama;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vrexperiences);

        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
        panoWidgetView.setEventListener(new VrPanoramaEventListener());

        //download image and show it, but it doesn't show anything
        loadPanoImage();

        titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);

        buttonCitta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCitta);
        buttonCitta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!checkReady()) {
                    return;
                }
                titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonCitta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonMare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonMontagna.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadPanoImage();    //it doesn't show anything
                mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(SYDNEY);
                loadPanoImage();    //it doesn't show anything
            }
        }};

        //code for buttonMontagna and buttonMare as well, it's identical

        SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
            (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);

        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
                new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                        mStreetViewPanorama = panorama;
                        // Only set the panorama to INVALID on startup (when no panoramas have been
                        // loaded which is when the savedInstanceState is null).
                        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                            mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(INVALID);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    /**
     * When the panorama is not ready the PanoramaView cannot be used. This should be called on
     * all entry points that call methods on the Panorama API.
     */
    private boolean checkReady() {
        if (mStreetViewPanorama == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the Animate To Invalid button is clicked.
     */
    public void onGoToInvalid(View view) {
        if (!checkReady()) {
            return;
        }
        mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(INVALID);
    }

    //retrieves image from the assets folder and loads it into the VrPanoramaView
    private void loadPanoImage() {
        VrPanoramaView.Options options = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("demo2.jpg");
            options.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
            panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream), options
            );
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Fail", "Exception in loadPanoImage" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        panoWidgetView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vrExperienceActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
        android:id="@+id/pano_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="VR Experience"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="#0000F0"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCitta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Città" />

    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment"
        android:id="@+id/streetviewpanorama"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: @LucioB
a) those are the places I've tried to call loadPanoImage, but neither of them showed anything. It acts as nothing happens calling that method, the program keeps going to the other tasks. I'd like for images to be shown directly in VR when a button is clicked, or if that isn't possible to add the classic cardboard button in Street View mode to pass to VR view.
b) I mean the code isn't doing what I expected it to do. I thought that once I created VrPanoramaView in the layout and used it to show an image through `.loadImageFromBitmap` it would have shown the image I loaded from asset (I have an image saved on the virtual SD), and that once I was able to do that for a single image I would have found a way to do it for a whole path.
The code doesn't give any exception, I think I'm making a logic mistake or I didn't understand how VR api work.

EDIT: I've found that the java code is working, the problem was in the layout which didn't permit to see VrPanoramaView because it was obscured by StreetViewPanorama

Comment: Hi @OrokyC! In order to help you I need to know a few things: 
a) why loadPanoImage() is called in three places? Which one would be the correct one? I guess it is the last line of onClick handler.
b) what do you mean when you say the code isn't working? Do you get an exception? Have you tried to debug it and see for instance where does it break? 
Add this explaining by editing the original question so that we can help you understand the cause of the problem. Thanks